# How to check if cuda is installed correctly on Anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, cuda, anaconda

I have installed Cuda using following command on Anaconda

conda install -c anaconda cudatoolkit

Earlier I also have used following command to install Tensorflow GPU version

conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu

However, Tensorflow-gpu is not activated and when I run the  following script:

```
    from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
    print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

name: "/device:CPU:0"

device_type: "CPU"

memory_limit: 268435456

locality 
{
}
incarnation: 12015853371339101357
]

Answer (score 20):

If you install numba via anaconda, you can run  `numba -s` which will confirm whether you have a functioning CUDA system or not. On a linux system with CUDA:

```
$ numba -s

System info:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
__Time Stamp__
2018-08-27 09:16:49.622828

__Hardware Information__
Machine               : x86_64
CPU Name              : ivybridge
CPU Features          : 
aes avx cmov cx16 f16c fsgsbase mmx pclmul popcnt rdrnd sse sse2 sse3 sse4.1
sse4.2 ssse3 xsave xsaveopt

__OS Information__
Platform              : Linux-4.4.0-57-generic-x86_64-with-debian-jessie-sid
Release               : 4.4.0-57-generic
System Name           : Linux
Version               : #78~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Sat Dec 10 00:14:47 UTC 2016
OS specific info      : debianjessie/sid
glibc info            : glibc 2.2.5

__Python Information__
Python Compiler       : GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)
Python Implementation : CPython
Python Version        : 3.6.0
Python Locale         : en_US UTF-8

__LLVM information__
LLVM version          : 6.0.0

__CUDA Information__
Found 1 CUDA devices
id 0      b'GeForce GTX 970'                              [SUPPORTED]
                      compute capability: 5.2
                           pci device id: 0
                              pci bus id: 1
Summary:
    1/1 devices are supported
CUDA driver version   : 9020
CUDA libraries:
Finding cublas
    named  libcublas.so.8.0.88
    trying to open library...   ok
Finding cusparse
    named  libcusparse.so.8.0.61
    trying to open library...   ok
Finding cufft
    named  libcufft.so.8.0.61
    trying to open library...   ok
Finding curand
    named  libcurand.so.8.0.61
    trying to open library...   ok
Finding nvvm
    named  libnvvm.so.3.1.0
    trying to open library...   ok
    finding libdevice for compute_20... ok
    finding libdevice for compute_30... ok
    finding libdevice for compute_35... ok
    finding libdevice for compute_50... ok

__Conda Information__
conda_build_version   : not installed
conda_env_version     : 4.5.4
platform              : linux-64
python_version        : 3.6.0.final.0
root_writable         : False

__Current Conda Env__
absl-py                   0.1.10                   py36_0  
accelerate_cudalib        2.0                           0  
bleach                    1.5.0                    py36_0  
ca-certificates           2018.03.07                    0  
certifi                   2018.4.16                py36_0  
cffi                      1.9.1                    py36_0  
conda                     4.5.4                    py36_0  
conda-env                 2.6.0                h36134e3_1  
cryptography              1.7.1                    py36_0  
cudatoolkit               8.0                           3  
cudnn                     7.0.5                 cuda8.0_0  
decorator                 4.0.11                   py36_0  
html5lib                  0.9999999                py36_0  
idna                      2.2                      py36_0  
intel-openmp              2018.0.0             hc7b2577_8  
ipython                   5.3.0                    py36_0  
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py36_0  
libffi                    3.2.1                         1  
libgcc-ng                 7.2.0                h7cc24e2_2  
libgfortran               3.0.0                         1  
libgfortran-ng            7.2.0                hdf63c60_3  
libprotobuf               3.5.1                h6f1eeef_0  
libstdcxx-ng              7.2.0                hdf63c60_3  
llvmlite                  0.23.2           py36hdbcaa40_0  
markdown                  2.6.11                   py36_0  
mkl                       2018.0.1             h19d6760_4  
mpmath                    0.19                     py36_1  
nccl                      1.3.4                 cuda8.0_1  
numba                     0.38.1           py36h04863e7_0  
numpy                     1.12.1           py36he24570b_1  
openssl                   1.0.2o               h20670df_0  
path.py                   10.1                     py36_0  
pexpect                   4.2.1                    py36_0  
pickleshare               0.7.4                    py36_0  
pip                       9.0.1                    py36_1  
prompt_toolkit            1.0.13                   py36_0  
protobuf                  3.5.1            py36hf484d3e_0  
ptyprocess                0.5.1                    py36_0  
pyasn1                    0.1.9                    py36_0  
pycosat                   0.6.3            py36h0a5515d_0  
pycparser                 2.17                     py36_0  
pyculib                   1.0.2               np112py36_2  
pyculib_sorting           1.0.0                         8  
pygments                  2.2.0                    py36_0  
pyopenssl                 16.2.0                   py36_0  
python                    3.6.0                         0  
pytorch                   0.3.0           py36cuda8.0cudnn7.0_0  
readline                  6.2                           2  
requests                  2.12.4                   py36_0  
ruamel_yaml               0.11.14                  py36_1  
scipy                     1.0.0            py36hbf646e7_0  
setuptools                38.5.1                   py36_0  
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py36_1  
six                       1.10.0                   py36_0  
sqlite                    3.13.0                        0  
sympy                     1.1.1                    py36_0  
tensorflow                1.4.1                         0  
tensorflow-base           1.4.1            py36hd00c003_2  
tensorflow-tensorboard    1.5.1            py36hf484d3e_0  
tk                        8.5.18                        0  
traitlets                 4.3.2                    py36_0  
wcwidth                   0.1.7                    py36_0  
werkzeug                  0.14.1                   py36_0  
wheel                     0.29.0                   py36_0  
xz                        5.2.2                         1  
yaml                      0.1.6                         0  
zlib                      1.2.11               ha838bed_2  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
If requested, please copy and paste the information between
the dashed (----) lines, or from a given specific section as
appropriate.

=============================================================
IMPORTANT: Please ensure that you are happy with sharing the
contents of the information present, any information that you
wish to keep private you should remove before sharing.
=============================================================
```

On a Windows system without a working CUDA GPU:

```
(base) >numba -s
System info:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

__Time Stamp__
2018-08-27 09:17:58.167285

__Hardware Information__
Machine               : AMD64
CPU Name              : haswell
CPU Features          :
aes avx avx2 bmi bmi2 cmov cx16 f16c fma fsgsbase lzcnt mmx movbe pclmul popcnt
rdrnd sse sse2 sse3 sse4.1 sse4.2 ssse3 xsave xsaveopt

__OS Information__
Platform              : Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1
Release               : 7
System Name           : Windows
Version               : 6.1.7601
OS specific info      : 76.1.7601SP1Multiprocessor Free

__Python Information__
Python Compiler       : MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)
Python Implementation : CPython
Python Version        : 3.6.4
Python Locale         : sv_SE cp1252

__LLVM information__
LLVM version          : 5.0.0

__CUDA Information__
CUDA driver library cannot be found or no CUDA enabled devices are present.
Error class: <class 'numba.cuda.cudadrv.error.CudaSupportError'>

__Conda Information__
conda_build_version   : not installed
conda_env_version     : 4.5.9
platform              : win-64
python_version        : 3.6.4.final.0
root_writable         : True

__Current Conda Env__
alabaster                 0.7.10           py36hcd07829_0
apptools                  4.4.0                    py36_0    conda-forge
asn1crypto                0.24.0                   py36_0
astroid                   1.6.1                    py36_0
babel                     2.5.3                    py36_0
backports                 1.0                      py36_1    conda-forge
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.5                        py_1    conda-forge
bleach                    2.1.2                    py36_0
blosc                     1.14.3               he51fdeb_0
bzip2                     1.0.6                    vc14_1  [vc14]  conda-forge
ca-certificates           2018.4.16                     0    conda-forge
certifi                   2018.4.16                py36_0    conda-forge
cffi                      1.11.4           py36hfa6e2cd_0
chardet                   3.0.4            py36h420ce6e_1
cloudpickle               0.5.2                    py36_1
colorama                  0.3.9            py36h029ae33_0
conda                     4.5.9                    py36_0    conda-forge
conda-env                 2.6.0                h36134e3_1
configobj                 5.0.6                    py36_0
console_shortcut          0.1.1                h6bb2dd7_3
cryptography              2.1.4            py36he1d7878_0
cudatoolkit               8.0                           3    anaconda
curl                      7.59.0                   vc14_1  [vc14]  conda-forge
cycler                    0.10.0           py36h009560c_0
decorator                 4.2.1                    py36_0
docutils                  0.14             py36h6012d8f_0
entrypoints               0.2.3            py36hfd66bb0_2
envisage                  4.5.1                    py36_0    conda-forge
expat                     2.2.5                    vc14_0  [vc14]  conda-forge
fastcache                 1.0.2                    py36_0    conda-forge
freetype                  2.7                      vc14_1  [vc14]  conda-forge
future                    0.16.0                   py36_0    conda-forge
hdf4                      4.2.13                   vc14_0  [vc14]  conda-forge
hdf5                      1.10.1                   vc14_2  [vc14]  conda-forge
html5lib                  1.0.1            py36h047fa9f_0
icc_rt                    2017.0.4             h97af966_0
icu                       58.2             vc14hc45fdbb_0  [vc14]  anaconda
idna                      2.6              py36h148d497_1
imagesize                 1.0.0                    py36_0
intel-openmp              2018.0.0             hd92c6cd_8
ipykernel                 4.8.2                    py36_0
ipython                   6.2.1            py36h9cf0123_1
ipython_genutils          0.2.0            py36h3c5d0ee_0
ipywidgets                7.1.2                    py36_0
isort                     4.3.4                    py36_0
jedi                      0.11.1                   py36_0
jinja2                    2.10             py36h292fed1_0
jpeg                      9b               vc14h4d7706e_1  [vc14]  anaconda
jsoncpp                   1.8.1                    vc14_0  [vc14]  conda-forge
jsonschema                2.6.0            py36h7636477_0
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py36_4
jupyter_client            5.2.2                    py36_0
jupyter_console           5.2.0            py36h6d89b47_1
jupyter_core              4.4.0            py36h56e9d50_0
keyring                   13.2.1                   py36_0    conda-forge
krb5                      1.14.6                   vc14_0  [vc14]  conda-forge
lazy-object-proxy         1.3.1            py36hd1c21d2_0
libiconv                  1.15                     vc14_0  [vc14]  conda-forge
libnetcdf                 4.4.1.1                 vc14_10  [vc14]  conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.32           vc14h5163883_3  [vc14]  anaconda
libssh2                   1.8.0                    vc14_2  [vc14]  conda-forge
libtiff                   4.0.9                    vc14_0  [vc14]  conda-forge
libxml2                   2.9.8                    vc14_0  [vc14]  conda-forge
llvmlite                  0.22.0           py36ha794a7c_0
lz4-c                     1.8.1                    vc14_0  [vc14]  conda-forge
m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6
m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                         2
m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2
markupsafe                1.0              py36h0e26971_1
matplotlib                2.1.0                    py36_0    conda-forge
mayavi                    4.6.1               py36_vc14_0  [vc14]  conda-forge
mccabe                    0.6.1            py36hb41005a_1
menuinst                  1.4.11           py36hfa6e2cd_0
mistune                   0.8.3                    py36_0
mkl                       2018.0.1             h2108138_4
mpi4py                    2.0.0                    py36_1
mpmath                    1.0.0                      py_0    conda-forge
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1
nbconvert                 5.3.1            py36h8dc0fde_0
nbformat                  4.4.0            py36h3a5bc1b_0
notebook                  5.4.0                    py36_0
numba                     0.37.0          np113py36h3a37915_0
numexpr                   2.6.5                    py36_0    conda-forge
numpy                     1.13.3           py36hb69e940_3
numpydoc                  0.7.0            py36ha25429e_0
openssl                   1.0.2o                   vc14_0  [vc14]  conda-forge
packaging                 16.8             py36ha0986f6_1
pandoc                    1.19.2.1             hb2460c7_1
pandocfilters             1.4.2            py36h3ef6317_1
parso                     0.1.1            py36hae3edee_0
pickleshare               0.7.4            py36h9de030f_0
pip                       9.0.1            py36h226ae91_4
prompt_toolkit            1.0.15           py36h60b8f86_0
psutil                    5.4.3            py36hfa6e2cd_0
py4j                      0.10.7                    <pip>
pycodestyle               2.3.1            py36h7cc55cd_0
pycosat                   0.6.3            py36h413d8a4_0
pycparser                 2.18             py36hd053e01_1
pyface                    6.0.0                      py_1    conda-forge
pyflakes                  1.6.0            py36h0b975d6_0
pygments                  2.2.0            py36hb010967_0
pylint                    1.8.2                    py36_0
pyopenssl                 17.5.0           py36h5b7d817_0
pyparsing                 2.2.0            py36h785a196_1
pyqt                      5.6.0            py36h764d66f_6    conda-forge
pysocks                   1.6.7            py36h698d350_1
pytables                  3.4.3                    py36_8    conda-forge
python                    3.6.4                h6538335_1
python-dateutil           2.6.1            py36h509ddcb_1
pytz                      2018.3                   py36_0
pywin32                   222              py36hfa6e2cd_0
pywin32-ctypes            0.1.2                    py36_0    conda-forge
pywinpty                  0.5.1                    py36_0
pyzmq                     16.0.3           py36he714bf5_0
qt                        5.6.2                    vc14_1  [vc14]  conda-forge
qtawesome                 0.4.4            py36h5aa48f6_0
qtconsole                 4.3.1            py36h99a29a9_0
qtpy                      1.3.1            py36hb8717c5_0
requests                  2.18.4           py36h4371aae_1
rope                      0.10.7           py36had63a69_0
ruamel_yaml               0.15.35          py36hfa6e2cd_1
scipy                     1.0.0            py36h1260518_0
send2trash                1.5.0                    py36_0
setuptools                38.4.0                   py36_0
sfepy                     2018.1                   py36_0    conda-forge
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py36_2
sip                       4.18                     py36_1    conda-forge
six                       1.11.0           py36h4db2310_1
snappy                    1.1.7                    vc14_1  [vc14]  conda-forge
snowballstemmer           1.2.1            py36h763602f_0
sphinx                    1.7.1                    py36_0
sphinxcontrib             1.0              py36hbbac3d2_1
sphinxcontrib-websupport  1.0.1            py36hb5e5916_1
spyder                    3.3.0                    py36_2    conda-forge
spyder-kernels            0.2.4                      py_2    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.20.1           vc14h7ce8c62_1  [vc14]  anaconda
sympy                     1.1.1                    py36_0    conda-forge
tbb                       2018_20171205            vc14_0  [vc14]  conda-forge
TC-Python                 2018.2.14768              <pip>
terminado                 0.8.1                    py36_1
testpath                  0.3.1            py36h2698cfe_0
tornado                   4.5.3                    py36_0
traitlets                 4.3.2            py36h096827d_0
traits                    4.6.0                    py36_1    conda-forge
traitsui                  6.0.0                      py_1    conda-forge
typing                    3.6.4                    py36_0
urllib3                   1.22             py36h276f60a_0
vc                        14                   h0510ff6_3
vs2015_runtime            14.0.25123                    3
vtk                       8.1.0             py36_vc14_200  [vc14]  conda-forge
wcwidth                   0.1.7            py36h3d5aa90_0
webencodings              0.5.1            py36h67c50ae_1
wheel                     0.30.0           py36h6c3ec14_1
widgetsnbextension        3.1.4                    py36_0
win_inet_pton             1.0.1            py36he67d7fd_1
wincertstore              0.2              py36h7fe50ca_0
winpty                    0.4.3                    vc14_2  [vc14]  conda-forge
wrapt                     1.10.11          py36he5f5981_0
wxpython                  4.0.0rc1.dev3440+0f9b36e          py36_0    conda-forg
e
yaml                      0.1.7            vc14hb31d195_1  [vc14]  anaconda
zlib                      1.2.11           vc14h1cdd9ab_1  [vc14]  anaconda
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

If requested, please copy and paste the information between
the dashed (----) lines, or from a given specific section as
appropriate.

=============================================================
IMPORTANT: Please ensure that you are happy with sharing the
contents of the information present, any information that you
wish to keep private you should remove before sharing.
=============================================================
```

Comment: thanks, however, i solved this issue by uninstalling the Cuda from anaconda and reinstalled it from the Cuda website.

Comment: @Nhqazi: Could please you either write and then accept your own answer, upvote or accept this wiki answer or delete this question rather than leave it lying around on the unanswered queue for the CUDA tag