# Tensorflow not recognizing NVIDIA GEFORCE RTX 2070 (only CPU)

Tags: python, ubuntu, tensorflow

**UPDATE: After more googling and research I have discovered that Tensor flow doesn't support CUDA 10.1 and only support VUDA 10.0 as of Feb 2019. So I will have to downgrade to CUDA 10.0 to work with the current TF version**

**TLDR: CUDA is installed and CUDNN is working but I can't get Tensorflow to recognize my NVIDIA GEFORCE RTX 2070, it only shows my CPU as avaiable devices. By Running this.**

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib

device_lib.list_local_devices()
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
 device_type: "CPU"
 memory_limit: 268435456
 locality {
 }
 incarnation: 14262450855498090337, name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0"
 device_type: "XLA_CPU"
 memory_limit: 17179869184
 locality {
 }
 incarnation: 1345793131978591054
 physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device"]
```

**Long Version**
I am trying to use Cuda on Ubnutu to decrease the training time for my machine learning algos. 
Keras == 1.0.7
TensorFlow = 1.13.1

This question is similar but does not help. My results are fine as well.

[How to check if cuda is installed correctly on Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52027384/how-to-check-if-cuda-is-installed-correctly-on-anaconda)

Nvidia Drivers (10.1) as required by my graphics card (NVIDIA RTX 2070):

```
nvidia-smi
Mon Apr 15 18:39:13 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 418.56       Driver Version: 418.56       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 2070    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   42C    P8     7W /  N/A |      0MiB /  7952MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Then checking my CUDA installation: (10.1 as required by my graphics card)

```
nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Feb__8_19:08:17_PST_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.105
```

Everything seems to look good so far. But when I try to 
Test my Cuda and Cudnn installation
There is lots of text that runs through here but I did the following commands.

```
cd cudnn_samples_v7/mnistCUDNN/
make clean && make
result is successful
./mnistCUDNN
lots of text followed by:
Result of classification: 1 3 5
Test passed!
```

So with all of these verification it seems that CUDA and CUDNN is up and running on my system. However when I try to check in TensorFlow or in Keras it doesn't show my GPU as available.

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib

device_lib.list_local_devices()
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
 device_type: "CPU"
 memory_limit: 268435456
 locality {
 }
 incarnation: 14262450855498090337, name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0"
 device_type: "XLA_CPU"
 memory_limit: 17179869184
 locality {
 }
 incarnation: 1345793131978591054
 physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device"]
```

I followed this guide for a GPU enabled Tensorflow version.

https://medium.com/@cjanze/how-to-install-tensorflow-with-gpu-support-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-with-cuda-10-nvidia-gpu-312a693744b5

His showed the NVIDIA GEFORCE RTX 2070 as available

Comment: @talonmies reason for downvote?

Comment: I don't know, you will have to ask the two people whom down voted this. I just voted to close and removed a tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After more googling and research I have discovered that Tensor flow doesn't support CUDA 10.1 and only support CUDA 10.0 as of Feb 2019. So I will have to downgrade to CUDA 10.0 to work with the current TF version